# How to use LINQ join on two DataTables to fill empty fields with 0 or null when one DataTable has no matching records

Tags: c#, .net, linq, join

I have a problem joining two DataTables using LINQ.

Tables have columns like this:

```
table1        table2
ID, name       ID, stock
1, item1       1, 100
2, item2       3, 50
3, item3
```

I used LINQ to join like this:

```
DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();
dtResult.Columns.Add("ID", typeof(string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("name", typeof(string));
dtResult.Columns.Add("stock", typeof(int));

var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
             join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
             on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID")

             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
             {
                dataRows1.Field<string>("ID"),
                dataRows1.Field<string>("name"),
                dataRows2.Field<int>("stock"),
              }, false);
result.CopyToDataTable();
```

The problem is that the result only shows IDs which are in the table2:

```
dtResult
ID, name, stock
1, item1, 100
3, item3, 50
```

I need to show the missing items, too. This is the desired result:

```
dtResult
ID, name, stock
1, item1, 100
2, item2, 0  //Prefer if it is "0", otherwise can be left "null"
3, item3, 50
```

I believe I should do left outer join, but I do not have enough knowledge about LINQ.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

This will let you default to 0 if the row doesn't exist in table2:

```
var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
             join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
             on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID") into lj
             from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
             select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
             {
                dataRows1.Field<string>("ID"),
                dataRows1.Field<string>("name"),
                r == null ? 0 : r.Field<int>("stock")
              }, false);
```

MSDN [source](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397895.aspx)

Comment: how to add two on clause like on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID") && on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID1") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID1")

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
var result =
from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable() on dataRows1.ID  equals dataRows2.ID into ps
from r in ps.DefaultIfEmpty()
select new { C= dataRows1 , r == null ? 0 : dataRows2.Stock};
```

Answer (score 2):

you simply need use [join..into clause](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb311040.aspx) like this

```
var result = from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
         join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
         on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID") into rows
         from row in rows.DefaultIfEmpty()
         select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
         {
            dataRows1.Field<string>("ID"),
            dataRows1.Field<string>("name"),
            row==null? null : row.Field<int>("stock"),
          }, false);
```

Comment: This will throw null reference exceptions since the default for DataRow is null

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
var result =
    from dataRows1 in table1.AsEnumerable()
    join dataRows2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
    on dataRows1.Field<string>("ID") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("ID") into lj
    from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
    select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
    {
        dataRows1.Field<string>("ID"),
        dataRows1.Field<string>("name"),
        r == null ? 0 : dataRows2.Field<int>("stock")
    }, false);
```

Comment: Where is 'dtResult' defined?

Comment: @Fandango68 In OP's code up in the question (`DataTable dtResult = new DataTable();`)