# How to join two tables using c# 4.0?

Tags: c#, linq, c#-4.0, datatable

I have the same issue as here is [LINQ join two DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables)
but my datatables are made on runtime like

```
DataTable dtTML = (DataTable)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(Convert.ToString(data.Json.Args[0]["TML"]), (typeof(DataTable)));
```

the solution that someone gave is fine but I am getting error on datarows2 at

```
select dtResult.LoadDataRow(new object[]
{
  dataRows2.Field<int>("stock") // here is error : does not exist in current context
}
```

while dataRows1.Field(s) are fine

Comment: Apparrently there is no column value with that name for the given datarow.  Not sure what else you're expecting to hear, or what that has to do with joining two tables.

Comment: Agreed, do your data tables have a `"stcok"` column?

Comment: Yes, I am saying my datatables are on runtime

Answer (score 1):

I can't see what's wrong with this approach :

```
DataTable dt1 = new DataTable();
dt1.Columns.Add("PK", typeof(int));
dt1.Columns.Add("Data1", typeof(int));

DataTable dt2 = new DataTable();
dt2.Columns.Add("FK", typeof(int));
dt2.Columns.Add("Data2", typeof(int));

dt2.Rows.Add(1, 5000);
dt1.Rows.Add(1, 1000);

var Result = (from r1 in dt1.AsEnumerable()
              join r2 in dt2.AsEnumerable()
              on r1["PK"] equals r2["FK"]
              select new
              {
                  A = r1.Field<int>("Data1"),
                  B = r2.Field<int>("Data2"),
                  //  choose more columns if any
              }).ToList();
```

You can do whatever you want using it. If you need the result to be a Datatable , just use this method [ **ListToDataTable** ] to convert List to DataTable:

```
public static DataTable ListToDataTable<T>(List<T> items)
{

    System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptorCollection properties =
    System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
        table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
    foreach (T item in items)
    {
        DataRow row = table.NewRow();
        foreach (System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
            row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
        table.Rows.Add(row);
    }
    return table;
```