# Relation between DataTables inside DataSet from Database

Tags: c#, loops, join, datatable, dataset

I have got some DataTable inside a DataSet which are coming from database.
All of them have got some columns, but there are two colums that tell me the "relation": code and date.
For example:

```
DataTable1: Code: 'V1' DATE: '20150202' AnotherColumX: Value
DataTable2: Code: 'V1' DATE: '20150201' AnotherColumY: Value AnotherColumZ:Value
            Code: 'V1' DATE: '20150202' AnotherColumS: ValueX AnotherColum3:ValueX
DataTable3: Code: 'V1' DATE: '20150201' AnotherColumF: Value AnotherColumY:Value
            Code: 'V1' DATE: '20150202' AnotherColumR: ValueX AnotherColumD:ValueX
            Code: 'V1' DATE: '20150202' AnotherColumT: ValueX AnotherColumD:ValueX
```

I want loop the DataSet and take from each datatable the combination of day and code, and make something with this(like making another dataset with each combination). Here I have got two possible combinations: ('V1','20150201') and ('V1','20150202'), but coul be a lot.

I would appreciate help to decide how to do: I have thought to make another DataTable with the relation, but It would be hard. Another possibility is to take all the possibles combinations and loop for each DataTable.
Any suggestion how would be the best way to continue?
Thanks.

Comment: Did you try LINQ? 
[LINQ join two DataTables][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables

Comment: It is going to be the best choice. Thanks