# Display multiple data table in DataGrid View in winForms

Tags: c#, winforms, datagrid

I have faced a problem that I have a set of data tables in a dataset.I want to show them in a `DataGrid` view but It can only show one datatable.Is there any way to show more that one data table in a grid view?I mean more than one without any relation defined among tables.
Here is how I have added my data to a dataset

```
 DataSet ds = new DataSet();


        DataTable RunoffEnergy = new DataTable();
        RunoffEnergy.Columns.Add("RF");
        RunoffEnergy.Columns.Add("LD");
        RunoffEnergy.Columns.Add("DT");
        RunoffEnergy.Columns.Add("K(DT)");
        RunoffEnergy.Columns.Add("K(LD)");
        RunoffEnergy.Columns.Add("KE");
        RunoffEnergy.Rows.Add();
        RunoffEnergy.Rows[0][0] = this.RF.ToString();
        RunoffEnergy.Rows[0][1] = this.Ld.ToString();
        RunoffEnergy.Rows[0][2] = this.Dt.ToString();
        RunoffEnergy.Rows[0][3] = this.K_Dt.ToString();
        RunoffEnergy.Rows[0][4] = this.K_Ld.ToString();
        RunoffEnergy.Rows[0][5] = this.Ke.ToString();


        //
        DataTable EstimationOfRunoff = new DataTable();
        EstimationOfRunoff.Columns.Add("Rc");
        EstimationOfRunoff.Columns.Add("Qe");
        EstimationOfRunoff.Columns.Add("Q");
        EstimationOfRunoff.Rows.Add();
        EstimationOfRunoff.Rows[0][0] = this.Rc.ToString();
        EstimationOfRunoff.Rows[0][1] = this.Qe.ToString();
        EstimationOfRunoff.Rows[0][2] = this.Q.ToString();

        //
        DataTable DetachmentOfSoilParticles = new DataTable();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("Fc", typeof(double));
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("Fs");
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("Fz");
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("F", typeof(double));
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("Hc");
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("Hz");
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("Hs", typeof(double));
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Columns.Add("H");
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows.Add();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][0] = this.Fc;
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][1] = this.Fs.ToString();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.Fz.ToString();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.F.ToString();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.Hc.ToString();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.Hs.ToString();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.Hz.ToString();
        DetachmentOfSoilParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.H.ToString();
        //
        DataTable ImidiateDepositionOfSoil = new DataTable();
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Columns.Add("Nfc", typeof(double));
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Columns.Add("Nfs");
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Columns.Add("Nfz");
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Columns.Add("DEPc", typeof(double));
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Columns.Add("DEPs");
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Columns.Add("DEPz");
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows.Add();
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows[0][0] = this.Nfc;
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows[0][1] = this.Nfs.ToString();
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows[0][2] = this.Nfz.ToString();
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows[0][2] = this.DEPc.ToString();
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows[0][2] = this.DEPs.ToString();
        ImidiateDepositionOfSoil.Rows[0][2] = this.DEPz.ToString();
        //
        DataTable DeleveryOfDetachedParticles = new DataTable();
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Columns.Add("Gc", typeof(double));
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Columns.Add("Gs");
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Columns.Add("Gz");
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Columns.Add("G", typeof(double));
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Rows.Add();
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Rows[0][0] = this.Gc;
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Rows[0][1] = this.Gs.ToString();
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.Gz.ToString();
        DeleveryOfDetachedParticles.Rows[0][2] = this.G.ToString();
        //
        DataTable TransportCapesity = new DataTable();
        TransportCapesity.Columns.Add("Tc", typeof(double));
        TransportCapesity.Columns.Add("Ts");
        TransportCapesity.Columns.Add("Tz");
        TransportCapesity.Columns.Add("T", typeof(double));
        TransportCapesity.Rows.Add();
        TransportCapesity.Rows[0][0] = this.Tc;
        TransportCapesity.Rows[0][1] = this.Ts.ToString();
        TransportCapesity.Rows[0][2] = this.Tz.ToString();
        TransportCapesity.Rows[0][2] = this.T.ToString();
        //




        ds.Tables.Add(DeleveryOfDetachedParticles);
        ds.Tables.Add(EstimationOfRunoff);
        ds.Tables.Add(DetachmentOfSoilParticles);
        ds.Tables.Add(ImidiateDepositionOfSoil);
       // ds.Tables.Add(DeleveryOfDetachedParticles);
        ds.Tables.Add(TransportCapesity);
```

these data does not have any relations.they are just the results of some calculations
If it is not possible how Can I display these data in a user friendly way?
Thank you so much

Comment: show some code first

Comment: IF the tables have no relations between each other, then add separate datagrid for all tables. Or define a `DataTable` and using `foreach` loop, add all the `dataTables`  in the new `datatable`. Try `forech (DataRow row in Table1.Rows) { newDataTable.Rows.Add(...)` (will be bit tricky). Do it only if it's not huge data. If so, use separate `dataGrids`.

Comment: @DhavalR thanks..If I add them to one datagrid what will happen to columns?As you can see there is a diffrent set of columns in each one and I dont want to have some emply cells in my datagrid..Is there any better solutions to show these results to user?

Comment: If you really want to show data in a single `dataGrid`, you could try third party control. One of them is `SourceGrid`.

Answer (score 1):

One option: Perform Join operation on these tables in Linq, Store result into a data table;then assign this new datatable as datasource of grid.

this might be helpfull to join data tables in linq -[LINQ join two DataTables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables)

Comment: Does it need any relations?and also what about the columns that are not same in tables