# Datagridview with two datasources

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have two tables one is them main table contains (id, Date, TestID, Result)
and the orther is a lookup table (TestID, TestName)

I want to show data like this in datagridview:

Id , Date, Test 1, Test 2, Test 3, Result.

and to be able to save it, is this possible? and how to start

Comment: from the look up table test, instead if testID , I want it to get name and put it as columns

Comment: If I understand your data structure, then for each test there should be a different row in the main table, so it doesn't make much sense to do all 3 tests in a single row, since they have different values for id and potentially date and result

Comment: No actually each test is performed daily at different time, the user wants it as an excel sheet so I want it to be 
Time: test Names and results under test name, is it possible?

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps you could combine the data from each of your datasources into a single dataset and then assign that dataset as the source of your dataview. However, without further info it's hard to speculate on possible solutions.

However ..

You can combine your resultsets into one DataTable using two SqlDataAdapter to fill the DataTable from the two databases respectively. Here is an example.

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    using(SqlDataAdapter a1 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [user1]", "Data Source=DBServer1;Initial Catalog=Database1;User ID=user;Password=***"))
    a1.Fill(dt);

    using(SqlDataAdapter a2 = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM [user2]", "Data Source=DBServer2;Initial Catalog=Database2;User ID=user;Password=***"))
    a2.Fill(dt);
```

***ABOVE IS JUST EXAMPLE its not the 100% correct method to do it starting with the connection to the Database , but its something for you to start and think about it ****

a1.Fill(dt) will initialize the DataTable and fill it. a2.Fill(dt) just adds rows to the DataTable dt from the other resultset. This example assumes that the two data sources have the same schema. If not, you have to prepare the datatable to accomodate both resultsets.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Certainly, the relationship between the records of first table by the second table need to a shared columns. For example, tables have ID column and it's shared between table one and two, so best way is [JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables) tables on two DataTables or Merge by [DataTable.Merge Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.merge(v=vs.110).aspx) on .NET.
Other way is, Concatenates two sequences by [Enumerable.Concat Method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb302894(v=vs.100).aspx)

---

References:

[How to: Concatenate Two Sequences (LINQ to SQL)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb386979(v=vs.100).aspx)

[DataTable.Merge Method (DataTable)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fk68ew7b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Comment: Yes, you can create one StoredProcedure or View in Sql to Insert or Update that records.
You need just a ID to doing any job on data