# RDLC- use more the one dataset within the same table

Tags: c#, wpf, dataset, rdlc, lookup

In my  wpf application i have rdlc reports.

In one of the reports i have a table `Countries` with `idntCountry` in one `DataSet` -and the `countryName` is in a different `DataSet`
So my question is:
how do i build a table that would take values from more then one `DataSets`? i tried using the `Lookup` function but i keep on getting a the error:

> Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current dataset scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified dataset scope

Technically, everything i try doing gives me that error.

What am i doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to join the two datasets. You can do this by creating a new view in your [dbms](http://searchsqlserver.techtarget.com/definition/database-management-system) in which you join them by using queries, or you could use linq.

An example of using linq can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables).

Comment: but then how i set the dataset in the report? in rdlc reports are not query based..

Comment: How are you trying to add the datasets now? You just join the datatables and then add that single new dataset as your datasource, the same way you did as before. Here is some more [documentation](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/326080) that could help you.

Comment: seems very not elegant.. no cleaner way to do that?

Comment: What dbms are you using? The easiest way is to create a new view there in which you join the two tables and then create a new DataSet for the view in C#.

Comment: Is it not possible to join two datasets directly within a report? For performance reasons, there are times when this would actually be MUCH BETTER than joining directly in the database. For example, suppose you have a few hundred thousand detail records which get pushed into a report. Each of those detail records has one of a small number of coded but somewhat lengthy (i.e. 40 characters each) descriptions which print per detail record. If the report is run on a different server than the DBMS, it is much more efficient to send the detail and codes datasets separately and merge on the client.

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin - I'm having trouble understanding your train of thought. You believe it to be more efficient to request 2 datasets separately and have them  merge on client side? This would still require your client to loop trough both sets in order to match the header with the details. It is possible but don't you think it's much simpler to have the DBMS join the datasets before sending it to the client?

Comment: @Oceans, uh yes it is much more efficient to loop through and join the datasets on the application server when one dataset has hundreds of thousands of detail records (and all you are passing from that table is a couple of Ids) and the table you are joining on has a total of perhaps 25 records with a relatively lengthy description. The savings in bandwidth is considerable. It is definitely faster in my environment to allow C# to merge the datasets.

Comment: @AnthonyGatlin, I understand now. In your specific situation using linq might be the better solution then. Or you could add both datasets and create the tablix for your largest dataset and use the [Lookup Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-design/report-builder-functions-lookup-function?view=sql-server-2017) to find the matching data from your second dataset.