# C# cross join datatable

Tags: c#, join, datatable, cross-join

How to obtain cross join for two datatables in C#

```
dataTable1 - 
          col1 
           a    
           b    

dataTable2 - 
          col2
           c
           d
```

I want output as follows:

```
dataResult - col1 col2 
               a    c 
               a    d   
               b    c   
               b    d
```

How this can be achieved?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [LINQ join two DataTables](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it:

```
var results = from dt1 in dataTable1.AsEnumerable()
              from dt2 in dataTable2.AsEnumerable()
              select new { dt1, dt2 };
```

Comment: Thanks, this has helped

Answer (score 0):

you can just join two tables of this,

```
SELECT A.col1,B.col2 FROM dataTable1 A JOIN datatable2 B
```