# Perform functions based on 2 datatables

Tags: c#, arrays, datatable

I have looked around for answers and have found nothing that works for what I am trying to do.

I have 2 datatables, 1 imported from an Excel sheet - the other created in C# event. Datatable 1 contains quantities of signs per shipment, or kit. The names/types of the signs are SVL-01, SVL-02, etc. Datatable 2 contains these same sign names/types, but also has the weight of each single sign of each type. I am trying to iterate my way through datatable 1, calculate the weight of each item and place a sum column and sum for each row.

Basically - where Datatable 1 ColumnName = Datatable 2 sign name, weight variable would = the weight listed in Datatable 2.

I am pretty sure I did not load images correctly.

[Datatable 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bSMXf.png)

Comment: the attached image is datatable 2, not 1

Comment: I don't have a full solution, but you should maybe look at joining your two datatables together using LINQ.

Comment: That is one of the things I found researching how to do this. But when I add them together, I am still not sure how to variably index to get the correct weight for the correct column.

Comment: Please add a more complete sample of the data for both tables, in the question not as an image. Also, what format do you want for the result?

Comment: Hmm - not sure how to add the table info in here. When I try to paste it wraps horribly.

Comment: Ascii tables are fine here. Paste it in as text, select the text with your mouse or Shift+cursor keys, then click the `{}` code formatting button.

Comment: DataTable1 -
box num | store num | kit id | SVL-01 | SVL-02 | SVL-03 | SVL-04 | etc
:-----------:|:-------------:|:------:|:----------:|:-----------:|:---------:|:-----------:|:-----
      1       |        3        |    1   |      13    |      8       |     14    |       22    |

@halfer - i am lost. do not see a code formatting button anywhere. Tried looking at the formatting page and this is what I could come up with. Sorry again - very much newb.

Comment: You can use code formatting for tables in questions: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks

Comment: yeah - for some reason I am missing that handy little menu bar.

Answer (score 0):

I used a [previous solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables) as a basis for producing something closer to your needs:

```
/* setup schema and sample data */
            DataTable kit = new DataTable("Kits");
            kit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Kit ID"));
            kit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sign Type"));
            kit.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sign Count", typeof(int)));


            DataTable signs = new DataTable("Signs");
            signs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sign Type"));
            signs.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Sign Weight", typeof(int)));

            DataRow rowBuffer = kit.NewRow();

            rowBuffer["Kit ID"] = "Kit 1";
            rowBuffer["Sign Type"] = "SVL-01";
            rowBuffer["Sign Count"] = 4;

            kit.Rows.Add(rowBuffer);

            rowBuffer = signs.NewRow();

            rowBuffer["Sign Type"] = "SVL-01";
            rowBuffer["Sign Weight"] = 44;

            signs.Rows.Add(rowBuffer);

            DataTable kitWeight = new DataTable();
            kitWeight.Columns.Add("Kit Type", typeof(string));
            kitWeight.Columns.Add("Kit Weight", typeof(int));

            /* join table and produce output set */

            var result = from dataRows1 in kit.AsEnumerable()
                         join dataRows2 in signs.AsEnumerable()
                         on dataRows1.Field<string>("Sign Type") equals dataRows2.Field<string>("Sign Type") into lj
                         from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
                         select kitWeight.LoadDataRow(new object[]
                         {
                            dataRows1.Field<string>("Kit ID"),
                            dataRows1.Field<int>("Sign Count") * r.Field<int>("Sign Weight")
                          }, false);

            /* iterate through results - we could do the multiplication here or like we did in the LINQ up above */
            foreach (DataRow v in result)
                Console.WriteLine(v["Kit Type"] + "\t" + v["Kit Weight"]);
```

Comment: I think this would require a complete reformatting of datatable1. The sign type is actually a column header in datatable 1.