# Merging two DataTables on a column

Tags: c#, join, datatable

I have two `DataTables`. I would like one table `joined` by the `column` `strike` which they share? I would like one table, where the columns of `table1` and `table2` are "merged/joined" with only one `strike` column, one `symbol` column, one `expiry` column, one `timestamp` column.

Table 1:

| symbol | expiry | strike | option_type | timestamp | option_mid | option_trade_count | option_prev_day_close | iv | open_interest | option_volume | delta | vega | theta | rho |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 140.0 | C | 15:59:59.000 | 17.325 | 12 | 16.1 | 0.2824 | 193 | 43 | 0.6709 | 0.3904 | -0.0294 | 43.0797 |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 145.0 | C | 15:59:59.000 | 14.425 | 11 | 13.25 | 0.2778 | 350 | 217 | 0.6067 | 0.415 | -0.0307 | 39.6381 |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 150.0 | C | 15:59:59.000 | 11.825 | 22 | 10.8 | 0.2742 | 2551 | 63 | 0.5397 | 0.4284 | -0.0312 | 35.8007 |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 155.0 | C | 15:59:59.000 | 9.5 | 10 | 8.7 | 0.2728 | 735 | 28 | 0.473 | 0.4295 | -0.0311 | 31.7564 |

Table 2:

| symbol | expiry | strike | option_type | timestamp | option_mid | option_trade_count | option_prev_day_close | iv | open_interest | option_volume | delta | vega | theta | rho |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 140.0 | P | 15:59:59.000 | 7.325 | 3 | 8.05 | 0.2801 | 375 | 22 | -0.3285 | 0.3901 | -0.0288 | -29.2865 |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 145.0 | P | 15:59:59.000 | 9.3 | 9 | 10.2 | 0.2749 | 903 | 46 | -0.3931 | 0.4149 | -0.03 | -35.3233 |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 150.0 | P | 15:59:59.000 | 11.675 | 14 | 12.75 | 0.272 | 2424 | 182 | -0.4606 | 0.4284 | -0.0307 | -41.8097 |
| AAPL | 2022-05-20 | 155.0 | P | 15:59:59.000 | 14.475 | 3 | 15.65 | 0.2696 | 216 | 21 | -0.5281 | 0.4295 | -0.0304 | -48.4802 |

**EDIT 1**

```
public class OptionFields
{
    public string root { get; set; }
    public string expiry { get; set; }
    public decimal strike { get; set; }
...
```

}

If I say this, I just get the values in `table2` (table1/table2 are now `List<OptionFields>`)

```
var result = from dataRows1 in table1
join dataRows2 in table2 on dataRows1.strike equals dataRows2.strike 
into lj
from r in lj.DefaultIfEmpty()
select r;
```

Comment: Can you please mention the expected output

Comment: The fields f table2 two would essentially be to the right of table 1 on the strike being the same, but not duplicating the columns listed on the OP

Comment: Oof, that's way more code than I want to write on a cellphone. Have you set a primary key on either table? If so, use it; loop on Ver one table and lookup the matching row from the other table, then extend the first table with all the extra columns the second one has and copy the new values over. If you have no PK, make a dictionary to index the Strike column to a particular row (loop over every row adding to index) then loop over the other looking up the strikes as you go

Comment: You can also take a look at putting suitable keys on each table and then calling Merge with missingschemaaction of Add - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-5.0#System_Data_DataTable_Merge_System_Data_DataTable_System_Boolean_System_Data_MissingSchemaAction_

Comment: And some duplicates for you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

I think you like to do a union client side. And with Datatables you can achieve this with merge.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.datatable.merge?view=net-5.0

Comment: I believe that merge adds rows to the table. In my case, there are no new rows created, but instead more columns. I want to take table2 and "paste" it based on strike, to the right of table1. So I want calls and puts on the same row on the same table, based on strke (and others but I will take strike). In the vernacular, this is called a "Straddle View"

Comment: For example: https://finance.yahoo.com/quote/AAPL/options?p=AAPL&straddle=true

Comment: Ok, sorry for misunderstanding. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/665754/inner-join-of-datatables-in-c-sharp