# C# LINQ join two DataTables with a common field

Tags: c#, winforms, linq, join, datatable

I've the following two exampled DataTables which shows data loaded from a DB:

```
              table1:                                 table2:
| pk |groupID|cField|field1|field2|    | pk |groupID|cField|field1|field2|
|----|-------|------|------|------|    |----|-------|------|------|------|
| 1  |   1   | 0.5  |  10  | $5   |    | 10 |   1   | 0.5  |  20  | $10  |
| 2  |   1   |  1   |  10  | $10  |    | 11 |   1   |  1   |  20  | $20  |
| 3  |   1   |  2   |  10  | $20  |    | 12 |   1   |  2   |  20  | $40  |
| 4  |   1   |  5   |  10  | $50  |    | 13 |   1   |  5   |  20  | $100 |                           


The expected result would be (dtAux):

|groupID|cField|t1_field1|t1_field2|t2_field1|t2_field2|
|-------|------|---------|---------|---------|---------|
|   1   | 0.5  |    10   |   $5    |    20   |   $10   |
|   1   |  1   |    10   |   $10   |    20   |   $20   |
|   1   |  2   |    10   |   $20   |    20   |   $40   |
|   1   |  5   |    10   |   $50   |    20   |   $100  |
```

Based on [this other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20760681/linq-join-two-datatables), I've tried the following code:

```
dtAux = new DataTable();
dtAux.Columns.Add("groupID"); 
dtAux.Columns.Add("cField"); 
dtAux.Columns.Add("t1_field1"); 
dtAux.Columns.Add("t1_field2"); 
dtAux.Columns.Add("t2_field1"); 
dtAux.Columns.Add("t2_field2");

IEnumerable<DataRow> qry = from t1 in table1.AsEnumerable() join t2 in table2.AsEnumerable()
                           on t1.Field<float>("cField") equals t2.Field<float>("cField")
                           where t1.Field<int>("groupID") == 1
                           select dtAux.LoadDataRow(new Object[] {
                                 t1.Field<int>("groupID"), t1.Field<float>("cField"),                                                                    
                                 t1.Field<int>("field1"), t1.Field<decimal>("field2"),                                                                   
                                 t2.Field<int>("field1"), t2.Field<decimal>("field2")
                           }, false);
```

Yet, it returns an empty table. Any hints or help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: isn't sql join better than linq joining datatables? readability, maintainablity. and if the datatable is just a memory storage and no database related, then defining a class is much more readable than datatable.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the suggestion.. in most of the forum's related subjects, this is not hardly enforced, so that's why I kept with the LINQ's approach. I'll consider it from now on (btw.. the real data comes from a DB but I just put the raw data for making it as simple as possible my case: I'll edit the post for clarify it).

Comment: Btw .. do you know why my post got a -1 vote? is it really that badly written and presented?

Comment: there's something you can improve. no need format that many tables. you only need give you class definitions, and the properties `t1_field2` make no sense to everyone (apparently this is faking, so put minimal question here)

Comment: ok, ok... I've redone the table's presentation: is it more readable now? (or in general, I should not give explicit data when I'm making a question?). And about *t1_field2* is faking... what does it mean? That I'm trying to trick with my question? (I know that I'm being so into the detail, but I wish to understand why I'm bothering the one's coming by)

Comment: no. you shouldn't present a table format. instead, mock some data using running code, just like what @tymtam does in the answer. the principle is **minimal reproducible** code, that we can copy paste and run.

Comment: names such as `foo` `bar` is much beter than `t1_field2`, because they are all fake ones, we prefer shorter ones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `qry` is not executed. You need `.CopyToDataTable()` to execute it.

```
qry.CopyToDataTable();
```

[Sample program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/P6826c)

Comment: Hello! Thanks for the answer. So... what's the function of *LoadDataRow()* if it's not the execution of the query? just a preparation of the table? (like with *DataTable.Clone()*)

Answer (score 2):

You could try Zip.

```
var table1 = new [] {
    new { pk = 1, groupID = 1, field2 = 5 },
    new { pk = 2, groupID = 1, field2 = 10 }
};

var table2   = new [] {
    new { pk = 10, groupID = 1, field2 = 10 },
    new { pk = 11, groupID = 1, field2 = 20 }
};

var table3 = table1.Zip(
    second: table2, 
    resultSelector: (t1, t2) => new { t1_field2 = t1.field2, t2_field2 = t2.field2});

foreach(var t3 in table3 )
{
    Console.WriteLine($"{t3.t1_field2}, {t3.t2_field2}");
}
```

This prints:

```
5, 10
10, 20
```